# Visual Studio 2008 - How do I setup automated copying of files from source to run/debug/deploy areas?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can someone give me a quick pointer to where abouts in VS2008 I would look to automatic the copying of files from a source area to (a) debug, (b) run, and (c) deployment areas?

Background - in this case it'll be a base sqlite database with empty tables...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a .NET project (VB .NET or C# : I believe C++ would need different steps) :

1. Add the file to your VS project.
2. Select the file inside VS, and set its properties :

   - **Build Action** : *Content*
   - **Copy To Output Directory** : *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*

Answer (score 2):

There would be two possibilities:

- Add the needed files to the project and set property "Copy to output directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer" or
- Open project properties and provide a post build script, that does the copying.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for post-build events? See project Properties->Build Events in Visual Studio.